# lpstat CUPS not working

Tags: printer, ubuntu-16.04, cups

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, and installed CUPS from the source. After this I changed the client.conf file and restarted CUPS. This restarting didn't finish because it was taking a very long time and then I turned off the computer. After this, typing 'lpstat' on my terminal is not working, saying that 'lpstat: Unauthorized.' I tried reinstalling CUPS through 'sudo apt install CUPS,' but the problem persists.

Also, if I open 'printer' in ubuntu I get the error 'There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'Unauthorized'.'

Can anyone help with my problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are probably better off using CUPS as bundled with the standard Ubuntu installers. (If there is some specific reason why you need to install CUPS from source, it might be helpful if you would explain what that reason is.) Probably the surest way to obtain Ubuntu with a working and patched CUPS installation would be to reinstall Ubuntu and then execute something along the following lines from Terminal: `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update && sudo restart now`.

Comment: Okay I get that. I installed CUPS manually because I didn't know Ubuntu had CUPS installed by default.

Comment: I have expanded my comment above and posted it as an answer. Please mark it as accepted if it solved your problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) should come with CUPS included. As such, there is no need to install CUPS from source on that operating system.

Installing from source risks compilation and installation errors, and also risks conflicts with the CUPS packages that are included with Ubuntu.

Probably the surest way to obtain Ubuntu Desktop with a working and patched CUPS installation would be to reinstall Ubuntu Desktop and then, once you have booted into that installation and gained Internet access, to execute something along the following lines from Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update && sudo restart now
```

*N.B. In future, you may find that questions about Ubuntu are better being asked at either of these two other StackExchange sites, which seem to feature a higher proportion of Ubuntu or other GNU/Linux users than SuperUser does:*

- *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)*
- *[Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com)*